# Floating action button not visible on scrolling after updating Google Support & Design Library

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've tried updating `com.android.support:appcompat` and `com.android.support:design` from: 25.0.1 to 25.1.0, as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

but I have found that my floating action button no longer appears when the activity scrolls.  My FAB behaviour is defined by the following:

```
public class MyFabBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public MyFabBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {

        // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child,
                               View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed < 0) {
            // User scrolled up -> hide the FAB
            animateFab(child, View.GONE);
        } else if (dyConsumed > 0) {
            // User scrolled down -> show the FAB
            animateFab(child, View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    static public void animateFab(FloatingActionButton fab, int visibility) {
        // ignore visibility passed in, and just make fab visible regardless
        if (fab.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            fab.show();
        }
    }
}
```

and my layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.MyFabBehavior"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="saveButton"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 58):

Updating from support lib `25.0.1` to `25.1.0` changes the `onNestedScroll` method of `CoordinatorLayout` in that the call is skipped for views whose visibility is set to `View.GONE`.

Calling `child.hide()` on the floating action button sets the view's visibility to `View.GONE`, which means now (as of 25.1.0), the `onNestedScroll` method call will be skipped for the floating action button in the future (because it skips all views whose visibility is `GONE`).

A workaround for this would be to set the view's visibility to `INVISIBLE` whenever you hide it.  This way, the `onNestedScroll` will not skip the view the next time a nested scroll is performed.

In order to achieve this, you can call

```
child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
            /**
             * Called when a FloatingActionButton has been hidden
             *
             * @param fab the FloatingActionButton that was hidden.
             */
            @Override
            public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                super.onShown(fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

in your `onNestedScroll` method.

Edit:  This issue has been submitted to the AOSP Issue Tracker at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230298

Comment: You saved me my job sir. THank you!

Comment: Wow this is insane!, we found the same problem updating to 25.1.1', thank for the suggestion.

Comment: There looks like a typo inside the override method. Should be `super.onHidden(fab)` I think.

Comment: It works like a charm. Here´s a C# version with Snackbar support: https://gist.github.com/xleon/2249aba606f5258957af505153ca91f3

Comment: 25.3.1 still has the same problem

Comment: Oh Boy! I have wasted hours thinking what has gone wrong since I last used the same code, which is not working after the version upgrade! Thanks, Worked like a charm! But this bug is annoying!

Answer (score 1):

in CoordinatorLayout 25.1.0 (

```
   for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getVisibility() == GONE) {
                // If the child is GONE, skip...
                continue;
            }
```

in 25.0.1

```
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            if (!lp.isNestedScrollAccepted()) {
                continue;
            }

            final Behavior viewBehavior = lp.getBehavior();
            if (viewBehavior != null) {
                viewBehavior.onNestedScroll(this, view, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
                        dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
                accepted = true;

        }
```

Comment: In the `onCreate()` of my `Activity` I do call `hide()` on the `FloatingActionButton`, so that it starts hidden and then appears on scrolling (via the defined behaviour).  Does calling `hide()` set its visibility to `GONE` and is your code snippet suggesting that the floating action button is therefore ignored forevermore during scroll events?  Surely not?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior has changed since support lib version `25.1.0`.

It must be the RecyclerView (Behavior) that triggers the FAB visibility change.

In other words, it's no longer the responsibility of the object that wants to react to have a behavior but on the object that moves to be aware of everything on screen.

Below is a link to a diff that shows the changes that are required to perform the upgrade:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/compare/master...ianhanniballake:scroll_aware_fab